# Empty LINQ query when a column is an empty string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a question about the following query:

```
var checkDropdowns =
(from d in db.SIMS_Data
 where d.LanguageID == LanguageID
 join s in db.CL_Surveys on new { X1 = d.SurveyCodeID, X2 = d.LanguageID } equals new { X1 = s.SurveyCodeID, X2 = s.LanguageID }
 where areas == s.SubjectAreaTitle && surveys == s.SurveyTitle 
 join f in db.CL_Freq on new { Z1 = s.FrequencyID, Z2 = d.LanguageID } equals new { Z1 = f.ID, Z2 = f.LanguageID }
 where f.LanguageID == d.LanguageID && f.ID == s.FrequencyID
 join p in db.CL_FreqPer on new { Y1 = s.FrequencyID, Y2 = d.PeriodID } equals new { Y1 = p.FrequencyID, Y2 = p.PeriodID }
 where frequencyID == p.PeriodID
 join y in db.CL_ReferenceYear on d.YearID equals y.ID
 where referenceYear == y.ReferenceYear
 select new { d, s.SubjectAreaTitle, s.SurveyShortTitle, s.SurveyTitle, f.FrequencyCode });
```

---

The thing is, when the **s.SurveyShortTitle** part of the **select** is an empty string, the query gives an empty list, but when the selection has something written in the DB, everything is allright. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: From what I can tell from your query, there is no reason why the value of `s.SurveryShortTitle` would affect whether the result of the query is an empty list or not as it isn't used within the query other than in your `select`.  The select will not filter the result set down.

Comment: Please show the rest of your code. The query you show isn't executed. Where and how do you actually execute it? I wouldn't be surprised to see an additional `where` there.

Comment: My bad. I was trying to use the table where I want to write in the entry, but at the beginning that thing doesn't exist at all. I made another query where I excluded db.SIMS_Data.